# Obtain the name of my columns from my django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to show some tables in my templates from my models and I need to know what are the fields from they.

Obtain the data is easy,

```
class fleet_bbdd_view(ListView):
    template_name = 'data_app/info-bbdd.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    model = info
    context_object_name = 'infoList'
```

Or if I want to specify,

```
def getData(request):
    data1 = info.objects.all() # Ex1, obtain all the data
    data2 = info.objects.order_by('id','-data_timestamp').distinct('id') # Ex2, obtain the last data from the distinct ids
    ctx = {'Data1':data1, 'Data2':data2}

return JsonResponse(ctx)
```

But, how can I obtain the name of my columns? Exists something like this?

```
cols = info.objects.fields()
```

I'm sure is not a pro question, but I really don't know what can I do.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get them by [**`get_fields()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields) method. For example:

```
cols = info._meta.get_fields()
```

It will return list of [**`model field instances`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#field-types). If you want to get the names of the column then try like this:

```
cols = [i.name for i in info._meta.get_fields()]
```

Comment: Yesterday I tried this option, `cols = info._meta.get_fields()`  and it gave me this error, `TypeError: Object of type ManyToOneRel is not JSON serializable`. But with your `list` with a `for loop` it works!! Thank you! :)